# Импортировать complexType из wsdl в другую wsdl с разными namespace

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

Есть две wsdl, в них разные namespace.
Есть ли возможность импортировать complexType из одной WSDL в другую WSDL?
Если да, то каков будет синтаксис импорта?

Comment: Но ведь wsdl - это описание сервиса. Если туда вставить некий тип, то описание перестанет соответствовать реально существующим методам.

Comment: Суть в том, что коллеги, которые мне направили несколько wsdl (различные сервисы), в каждой схеме используют один и тот же тип. Не очень удобно, что один и тот же тип данных в итоге генерируется в разные классы.
Я хотел вынести это тип только в одну wsdl, а в остальных его просто импортировать.